# How to make a phone call AND return to the original app afterwards

Tags: ios

If I use UIWebView to display a phone number and set the data detector type to UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber, then when I click on the number its possible to make a phone call.

*After the phone call has ended I am returned back to my app*.

However if I attempt to programatically invoke the phone app using

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:123456789"]];
```

or

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://123456789"]];
```

Then it is not possible to return back to my app after the call has finished.

Is it possible to be able to programmatically launch the phone app and then return back to my app after the call is finished, the same as if the user clicks on a number in a UIWebView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Apple does not allow this to occur, as when you do the openURL command, it will open that application, and since you cannot access anything within that application, you will have to re-enter your application yourself. You can however save your state in `NSUserDefaults`, and then have the user be able to go back to the same part of the app as when they left. Check here for help: [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH1-SW1)

Comment: But if you're listening to music and get a call, the phone switches to the call automatically, then switches back to music when the call is done....iOS does not expose that functionality in the API?

Comment: No. Like many other thing, Apple reserves such things for its own applications. Elitist, don't you think ? ;)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://123456789"]];`

use:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://123456789"]];`

`telprompt://` vs. `tel://`

This will pop up an alert view and the user will have to tap "call" but this returns to the app after the call is done.

Answer (score 2):

use for instance

```
NSString * telNummer;
NSString *osVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
if ([osVersion floatValue] >= 5.0) { 
    telNummer = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"telprompt://%@", person.telephoneNumber];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:telNummer]];
} else {
    telNummer = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"tel://%@", person.telephoneNumber]; 
    UIWebView *webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame]; 
    [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:telNummer]]]; 
    webview.hidden = YES; 
    // Assume we are in a view controller and have access to self.view 
    [self.view addSubview:webview]; 
    [webview release];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can send local notification 2-3 seconds after the dial app is visible to the user.
it's not perfect, but clicking on the local notification is and getting back to the original app, its easier the double click on the home button and switch app.

Answer (score 0):

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://your phone number"];
    [[UIApplication  sharedApplication] openURL:url];

Answer (score 0):

This might work?

```
UIWebView webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init]; 
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:123456789"]; 
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```